# Aquamacs (on Mac lion): whatever I write i being interpreted as "Enter"

Tags: python, osx-lion, aquamacs

I am editing a python script that I wrote a while ago, using aquamacs on Mac lion.

Whichever letter or number I type is being interpreted as "enter" (that is, I hit "g" for example, my text is dissrupted and a newline appears, but "g" does not appear). Restarting aquamacs, the terminal out of which I run it, or the whole computer did not help.

Other observations (that might or might not be connected):
- The script is located in a folder under Dropbox 
- The file has special attributes (that is an "@" appears at the end of the permissions, upon typing ls -lah)
- I might have hit a combination of Control, Apple and other keys that I should not have ....

Any solution to this would be very much appreciated (and my apologies, if that has been treated before).
Thanks!

Comment: Is the file read only? how did you open the file (sounds like you are in view-mode)

Comment: I don't think the [@ symbol is significant](http://serverfault.com/questions/151997/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-a-files-permission-settings), but like Mark said you may be trying to edit a read only file. Can you post the full output of `ls -la` for us? What happens if you copy that file from Dopbox to your local drive, and edit there? Does the status line (bottom of the frame) indicate the buffer is read only?

Comment: Also, what modes are active for that buffer (take a look in the mode line)?

Comment: Mark & Keith, thanks for your answers. I didn't say this before but I had tried all the possible chmod-commands (including chmod a+w, so that teh permissions are actually -rwxrwxrwx@). On top of that, copied the file out of the DropBox, doesn't help. In the meantime, I copy-pasted the code into a new aquamacs window. Then the problem disappeared until I did "save as" (outside of teh dropbox) ... then it reappears ... I am starting to not belive my own eyes anymore

Comment: The mode line (afetr saving) says "-:---\sname_of_my_script\tTop\s(1,19)\t(Python)", where "\s" is a space and "\t" are multiple spaces (looks like tab, but who knows). The line1-positionn19 is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I also met with this problem recently. 
You need to add minor mode Fill. Press on the Python in the mode line in mouse-3 way and choose Auto Fill.